# What's happening when I send to my own domain a mail?

Tags: php, apache, email

my php scripts usually send mail with users data to a mailbox on my own domain. So, the question is: does the mail go out from my server or it goes directly from apache to mail server? Does it pass trough ISP, DNS, etc?
Thank you very very much

In the header:
Received: (qmail 11910 invoked by uid 10001); 26 Mar 2012 23:59:23 +0200

Comment: shouldn't ever leave your domain(but there are a lot of configuration varables), you can check how the mail is routed by viewing the email headers or depending on the server there can be command lines to check. For exim you can run: exim -bt you@address.com

Comment: Depends entirely on your mail system's setup, but generally speaking, mail intended for 'local' addresses shouldn't ever be round-tripped through the "outside" world.

Comment: In the header..Received: (qmail 11910 invoked by uid 10001); 26 Mar 2012 23:59:23 +0200... does it help?

Comment: you can post the full mail header if you like, is there a particular reason you are asking? most people wouldn't care as long as the email arrived, how it was routed

Comment: I know Dagon, but sometimes my php scripts send sensible and private data over mail, so if the mail goes to the outside world, I need to do something in order to make it secure, else I have to make secure only SMTP transfer.

Comment: this is the full header:
Received: (qmail 13559 invoked by uid 10001); 27 Mar 2012 10:55:57 +0200
To: admin@mydomain.it
Subject: Mail from mydomain.it
X-PHP-Originating-Script: 10001:class.phpmailer.php
Date: Tue, 27 Mar 2012 10:53:57 +0200
From: test <webmaster@mydomain.it>
Message-ID: <c312221a75697b622xzv3aee98e7a9cb@mydomain.it>
X-Priority: 3
X-Mailer: PHPMailer 5.0.2 (phpmailer.codeworxtech.com)
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit
Content-Type: text/html; charset="utf-8"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it goes trough DNS but the address IP is on the server so it a sort of loopback. However, it go to the router first and goes back. Maybe Apache / PHP has a sort of something to prevent this but a regular TCP/IP connection will do that.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming PHP is configured to use the same MTA that also handles emails for your domain nothing will go through the wire.